# Istio VirtualService short name "vs" doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I've installed Istio 1.20 using Helm according to the instruction: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/

I'm trying to use alias for `VirtualService` -> `vs` but for some strange reason it doesn't work for me.

```
$ kubectl get virtualservice
NAME       GATEWAYS               HOSTS   AGE
bookinfo   ["bookinfo-gateway"]   ["*"]   129m

$ kubectl get vs
No resources found in default namespace.
```

At the same time `gw` shorthand works perfectly:

```
$ kubectl get gw
NAME               AGE
bookinfo-gateway   132m
```

I can definitely see `vs` short name is defined in `CustomResourceDefinition` for `virtualservices.networking.istio.io`:

```
spec:
  conversion:
    strategy: None
  group: networking.istio.io
  names:
    categories:
    - istio-io
    - networking-istio-io
    kind: VirtualService
    listKind: VirtualServiceList
    plural: virtualservices
    shortNames:
    - vs
    singular: virtualservice
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I want `vs` alias to be working.

I would expect `kubectl get virtualservice` and `kubectl get vs` to equally work.

Comment: In k8s cluster if two resources / crds are configured like istio (virutal service) and nginx (virtual server), in that case the alias wont yield any results for the command kubectl get vs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have multiple resources using the 'vs' shortname.

Try `kubectl api-resources`, look for the `SHORTNAMES` column and you may see another resource using that shortname. In my case it's `VolumeSnapshot` at `snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1`.

Comment: You're right. It was the same for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm can you create a virtual service in a "test" NS and run the below command,

```
kubectl get vs -n test
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace. Use `kubectl get namespaces` to view available namespaces. If the VirtualService is not in the default namespace, specify its correct namespace.

```
kubectl get vs -n <namespace-name>
```